# Key Value Pair Collection, where the values can be of multiple types?

Tags: asp.net, .net, generics, serialization, collections

Tl;dr I'd like to set up a collection of key value pairs, where the values can be of multiple types, but are also serializable with `ISerializable`. Is this possible, and if so how can I go about achieving it?

I'm trying to replace code in an existing system where `Hashtables` are stored in a `Session` variables, allowing developers to store multiple types of object within them against specified keys. I'm attempting to convert the system so it can use `SqlServer SessionState` (storing the `Session` data in a db, rather than in memory), which requires everything added to the `Session` object be `ISerializable`.

Hopefully this could be achieved somehow using my own Generic data class that wrappers the objects of multiple types in the collection? I just can't quite see how (I've used plenty of Generic collections, just never set up my own generic classes, so I'm struggling to see how I'd do this).

Many thanks in advance, for any advice on possible approaches to this.

Comment: What's the problem with simply `Dictionary<int, ISerializable>`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` where TValue has to implement ISerializable. Since Dictionary has all implementation you need and only is too permissive with TValue type, it is enough to create class that inherits Dictionary and adds generic constraint:

```
class DictionaryOfSerializables<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> where TValue : ISerializable
{ }
```

Comment: Belated thanks for your input Mr. Shadow, I've not been able to carry on with this work, but I promise I'll come back and tidy up this question when I can!